# Why do my enum definitions have different icons in Class View?

Tags: visual-c++, enums, visual-studio-2022, vs-classview

Sample `enum`:

```
enum class EnumCountType { Chairman, AuxiliaryCounsellor, Treasures, Presentations, Living, Conductor, Reader };
```

Class View:

[image]

All of these enums are created in the same way (at the top of the respective headers).

Yet, I see several types of icons in **Class View**:

- Tick
- Padlock
- Flag

Why is this? I never noticed it before.

Visual C++ MFC Dialog project in Visual Studio 2022.

---

I looked [Class View and Object Browser icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2022) but I can't see them there.

Comment: The padlock indicates a private class member, IIRC. Not sure about the others. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2019) is an out-of-date and non-English(ish) summary.

Comment: Those look like the source control status icons (except for the white flag): `blue lock` - file unchanged, "Checked in"; `red tick` - file changed, "Pending edit"; `green plus` - file not added to source control, "Pending add", I have only seen them in the Solution Explorer but not the Class View. Do you have any extensions that may have added them?

Comment: @PiersMyers Just used TortoiseGit from File Explorer and committed all changes. Now those icons don't have the little icon overlays. Must have been source control related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are source control status icons:

`blue lock` - file unchanged, "Checked in"

`red tick` - file changed, "Pending edit"

`green plus` - file not added to source control, "Pending add"

Never seen the white flag icon before, if you hover your mouse pointer over it then it should tell you what it means.

For me they are only shown in my Solution Explorer against files, I have never seen them in the Class View - perhaps it's a feature of TortoiseGit or C++ projects (I have only used C# projects with Git for Windows).

Comment: Thanks. I also notice on the link I added to my question that it does say: *If your project is included in a source control database, additional signal icons may be displayed to indicate source-control status, such as checked in or checked out.*.

Comment: Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2022